# ajax json decode returning undefined not data

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm trying to pull json data via ajax from a PHP script, but it is not working.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $response = array(
    'hello' => $row['name']
    );


    $responses[] = $response;

}

echo json_encode($responses);
```

Then I use this JavaScript

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/testFixGet.php?department=1',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'manufacturer=alpine,kicker',
    success: function(json) {
            alert(json['hello']);
     $('.result_new').html(json);
     }
});
});
```

The dialog presents: 'Undefined'

But, if I actually load the php page the data is json decoded and it looks like this:

```
[{"hello":"Rand McNally Soft Case for Most 5\" GPS"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll notice your JSON payload contains an array with one object element. Try

```
alert(json[0]['hello']);
```

Also, `getJSON()` is much more concise

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/testFixGet.php', {
        department: 1,
        manufacturer: 'alpine,kicker'
    }, function(json) {
        // loop over results
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var response = json[i];
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked, but I want to return every row, so would I do a foreach statement in my success function?

Comment: I've copied this exactly, but it is not doing anything, and it is not showing up in my firebug.

Comment: Scrath that, I just added a '.clickme'

Comment: @RPM Oops, missed that one. Was too focussed on the other bits

Comment: But, it is still only returning 1 result when I do this: $('.result_new').html(response.hello);

Comment: @RPM The `html()` method overwrites everything in the container. Perhaps you want to try `append()`?

Comment: @Phil let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1902/discussion-between-rpm-and-phil)

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the content type?

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

ANd by the way

```
[{"hello":"Rand McNally Soft Case for Most 5\" GPS"}]
```

it is an array so it would be

```
alert(json[0]["hello"]);
```

To loop

```
var bar = [{"a":"1"},{"a":"2"},{"a":"3"}]
$.each( bar, function(i, jObj){
   alert( jObj.a );

});
```

Comment: I had the header set to json, but would I execute a foreach statement inside the success function in order to return all the hello's?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {        
  $.getJSON('testFixGet.php', { manufacturer: "alpine,kicker", department: "1" },  function(json) {                     
            alert(json[0].hello);   
            $('.result_new').html(json);
  }  );
}
```